# Kernel not recognizing new devices from DKMS module?

Tags: linux, usb, kernel-modules, hid

I've done some work backporting the kernel modules for `hid-apple` and `bcm5974` (with lots of help from [SicVolo](https://github.com/SicVolo/hid-apple-3.19)) and writing DKMS scripts for them so I can maintain compatibility across kernel upgrades:

- [rfkrocktk/hid-apple-3.19](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/hid-apple-3.19)
- [rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19)

The patches are pretty straightforward, they just add support for these new USB product ids.

The problem I'm having is that even after installing these new kernel modules using DKMS, my devices are *never* bound to the right drivers, they're always bound to `usbhid` and then to `hid-generic`, where they should be going to be bound by `hid-apple` and `bcm5974` for the keyboard and trackpad respectively.

The changes are *really* simple and as far as I can tell, they should tell the kernel enough to [bind the right devices](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19/blob/master/bcm5974.c#L95-L98) to the [right drivers](https://github.com/rfkrocktk/bcm5974-3.19/blob/master/bcm5974.c#L161-L163).

Is there a step I'm missing in order to tell the kernel that it really should bind these devices to these drivers? Am I installing the modules in the wrong place in DKMS?

If I go through the hassle of rebinding the devices to the right drivers (ie: locate, lookup, unbind, bind), they work great and the patches are functioning as expected. But how do I get the kernel to bind things the right way *by default*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that I was installing the packages into the wrong directories in DKMS.

It's important to set `DEST_MODULE_LOCATION` to point to the directory within the kernel drivers in which your module is supposed to live. I was installing into `/updates`, but this was the wrong place. I had to move it to `/kernel/drivers/hid` to get it recognized.

The weird thing is that DKMS seems to still install the driver into `/extras` no matter what you pass here, but somehow this fixes it.